# Group a range of integers such as no pair of numbers is shared by two or more groups

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

This is a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185087/group-a-range-of-integers-such-as-no-pair-of-numbers-is-shared-by-two-or-more-gr?noredirect=1#comment67639450_40185087) from StackOverflow. I've been advised to post it on Mathematics by another user who clearly has more experience in combinatorics than myself, and, although I have my doubts, I hope he is right.

---

You are given two numbers, $N$ and $G$. The goal is to create an algorithm to split a range of integers $[1-N]$ in equal groups of $G$ numbers each, in reasonable time. Each *pair* of numbers must be placed in exactly one group. Order does not matter.

For example, given $N=9$ and $G=3$, I could get these 12 groups:

```
1-2-3
1-4-5
1-6-7
1-8-9
2-4-6
2-5-8
2-7-9
3-4-9
3-5-7
3-6-8
4-7-8
5-6-9
```

As you can see, each possible pair of numbers from 1 to 9 is found in exactly one group. I should also mention that such grouping cannot be done for every possible combination of $N$ and $G$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that such grouping cannot be done for every possible combination of N and G?

Comment: @Thanassis, aside from obvious `N≥G` condition - consider N=4 and G=3, for example. There is no way one can split numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4]` into groups of 3 such that each pair of numbers is covered. This set is even small enough to try to cover all possible combinations manually.

Comment: What you are describing is called a [block design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design) and has been studied pretty extensively. Specifically, you want an $(N,G,1)$-design. I suspect there are algorithms out there for generating them, as well as criteria for when they exist in the first place.

Comment: Talking about pairs of numbers makes me naturally think of edges in graphs. The problem can be regarded as finding a decomposition of $K_N$ into copies of $K_G$.

Comment: Although not stated, we can assume that $N\ge G$.I was confused a bit with the wording of the problem but it is clear to me now. Given the description of the problem $N = kG$, with $k$ being a positive integer. You can state this, instead of making the loose statement that not all combinations of $N$ and $G$ work.

Comment: @Thanassis, not necessarily. For instance, with $N=7$ and $G=3$ grouping also works fine.

Comment: @Joffan, could you please explain a bit more? I'm not very familiar with high mathematics, and searching on wiki for "decomposition" in math brings ambiguious results.

Comment: Oh you are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about pairs of numbers makes me naturally think of edges in graphs. Each pairing can be represented by an edge of the graph. Since we want all possible pairings (without repeats), we're looking at the desired state of a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) on $N$ vertices, $K_N$. Each group is a complete subgraph of $G$ vertices. that produces pairs in accordance with the edges The problem can be regarded as finding a decomposition of $K_N$ into copies of $K_G$ - a set of edge-disjoint subgraphs that account for all the edges in $K_N$.

There are $N(N-1)/2$ edges in $K_N$, and $N-1$ edges from each vertex, and similiarly there are $G(G-1)/2$ edges in $K_G$, and $G-1$ edges from each vertex. So as a minimum consideration we need:
$$\begin{align} G-1 &\mid N-1 \tag{1} \\
G(G-1)/2 &\mid N(N-1)/2 \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

- the first so that the $k=(N-1)/(G-1)$ groups involving any one element exhaust the edges from (pairs with) that element and
- the second to ensure that that the groups can exhaust all pairings exactly.

For example, with $G=3$, $N$ must be odd and either $N$ or $N-1$ must be divisible by $3$ (to satisfy the second condition). So, for example, $N=5, G=3$ is not possible. For $G=4

However for $(N,G) = (7,3)$, we have $2 \mid 6$ and $3 \mid 21$, so those criteria are met and the $K_7$ graph decomposes into $7$ $K_3$ graphs:

[image]

Numbering the vertices from $1$ at the top clockwise, this corresponds to groups  $\{1,2,6\},\{1,3,7\},\{1,4,5\},\{2,3,4\},\{2,5,7\},\{3,5,6\},\{4,6,7\}$

For $G=4$, the smallest $N$ for which divisibility is met is $13$, and that works as follows:

$\{1,2,3,4\}$
$\{1,5,6,7\}$
$\{1,8,9,10\}$
$\{1,11,12,13\}$
$\{2,5,8,11\}$
$\{2,6,9,12\}$
$\{2,7,10,13\}$
$\{3,5,9,13\}$
$\{3,6,10,11\}$
$\{3,7,8,12\}$
$\{4,5,10,12\}$
$\{4,6,8,13\}$
$\{4,7,9,11\}$

My expectation is that whenever the divisibility criteria are met, it will be relatively simple to generate the required sets just by tracking which pairings have been used.

Comment: Thanks! That's very insightful. I've been able to modify my code a bit so it would definitely determine which $N$ and $G$ are guaranteed to yield results. Unfortunately, it's exactly generating these sets that I have most trouble with: it goes perfect until I have 1 or 2 groups left, and then no possible groupings left. So I have to backtrack and try slightly different groupings, and try again, and try again... And this approach gives right results eventually, but it is very, very slow. Is it possible to if not predict these sets exactly, then at least somehow narrow the search?

Comment: @DeFazer What sort of $N$ and $G$ values are you working with? It might help me to work out your allocation issues. And you can click the checkmark next to my answer if you feel it has helped suitably :-)

Comment: to be honest, I'm not sure. Right now I'm just trying to determine possible algorithm efficiency and which values of $N$ and $G$ it can be expected to work with in reasonable time. But estimatively, I expect $N$ to be around 40 and $G$ to be around 6-10, although this is highly probable to change.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't accept your answer (yet), because at the moment it doesn't address the main issue - the time-efficient way to find such sets. I've already modelled this problem with graphs and even wrote some working code (you can actually examine it in the [SO duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40185087/4531903) of the question - I didn't repost it here because I thought that it won't be relevant to the mathematical side of problem), but the brute-force backtracking approach is very slow.